# Using Search Specification to Filter records on a Pick Applet in Siebel

Tags: siebel

I have a requirement to Filter records on the SR Contact Pick Applet,
The pick applet should only display records related to its Account.
Have tried using the search specification on the applet.

`[contact id]=[account id]`.

The main aim :
When raising a Service Request from the account screen the last name field which uses the **SR Contact Pick Applet**  which displays all contact record(all contacts on the system).

I want it to only display contacts of the account. i.e. Contacts Created under the accounts alone.

Any other suggestions aside search specification will be welcomed.
But am most likely sure its search specification.

Comment: How the fields that are mapped to this Pick Applet are configured in BC level?
You can also check the search spec in the PickList Level.

Comment: The filed are mapped from the contact BC.. I need a search specification to reduce the data to meet business requirement, do you have a sample siebel client and tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest configuration (non-scripted) solution would be to use a picklist constrain on the BC level.
On the Service Request bc, for the the field [Contact Last Name], under pickmap, check the Constrain field for Account Id.

This will filter the contacts to only show the contact of the account.

Comment: This works , but the requirement has changed from account - contact to account - designated contact..a new BC created from Contact called Designated contact. So the service request pick applet should only show designated contact

Comment: Well then a new field should be added on SR bc to hold the account designated contact. You can use the s_org_ext join to bring the designated contact id from account to SR. Then change the constraint on the contact picklist to point to this new field.